# Updating app to a newer api in google play store

Tags: android, api, google-play-console

I couldn't figure out from documentation, so I am asking here.

- I have an app present in Google Play Store with minsdk 15, which supports a lot of devices.
- Now I would like to update my app to minsdk 24, to use java 8 features.

After updating the app in google play, are old devices still be able to use the older version ? Or is my app seen only from devices with 24+ ?

Is it in general recommended to upgrade to 24+ to use java8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the first question only users who have installed the app before
  can use it but cant update it anymore, and new users with devices
  which have older SDK than 24 cant see your app in store.
- About your second question, this is your choice to use java8 features
  and ignore older devices or not. but general advise is not raising
  your minSDK.

You can handle each situation you need for minSDK 24+ like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N){ 
    // Devices with SDk 24+ 
} else { 
    // Devices with SDK 24- 
}
```

Comment: perfect answer. Thank you very much !

Comment: To complete this answer, you can if you want make your old version of the app still visible to users with SDK < 24. You can do this in the Play Console in your new release by keeping an artifact from the previous release. Play then selects the best APK based on the minSdkVersion of the APK and the SDK version of the user.